# Send email with Visual Basic and OpenEmail function

Tags: vb.net, email

I need to send many email with vb.net

I'm using the OpenEmail/Process.Start function
OpenEmail(user@gmail.com, "Subject", "Message")
or
Process.Start("mailto:user@gmail.com?subject=Message Title&body=Message Content")

My default client starts but I have to press the button for sending message.
I want that messages will be send without hit the button but directly from code.

Is there a way to do that with OpenEmail or Process.Start ?

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what OpenEmail is, but for Process.Start the answer is no. Alternatives are: (1) sending the mail directly though the mail server (using SMTP or the Web API of your mail provider) or (2) using a third-party library such as Redemption which claims to be able to send mails through Outlook despite of its mail scripting protections.